# Could not resolve dependencies for project: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sourceforge:kabeja:jar:0.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

> Could not resolve dependencies for project
> com.xxxx-xxxx:jar:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at
> net.sourceforge:kabeja:jar:0.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
> net.sourceforge:kabeja:jar:0.4: Could not transfer artifact
> net.sourceforge:kabeja:pom:0.4 from/to snapshots (http://snapshots):
> Transfer failed for
> http://snapshots/net/sourceforge/kabeja/0.4/kabeja-0.4.pom

Pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
        <artifactId>kabeja</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Settings.xml

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <url>http://snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>releases</id>
                <url>http://releases</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>jboss-public-releases</id>
                <url>http://jboss-public-releases/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I tried mvn clean -u, mvn clean, mvn install. But this is always failing. Even proxy settings are intact.

Comment: It seems repository is not configured correctly where the jar is found. `http://snapshots` doesn't seem a valid host.

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel For another dependency it is working fine. Hence I don't want to change my maven settings. Do u suggest any solution to this?

Comment: Have you defined any repository in your pom / setting.xml.

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel Yes, I did.

Comment: Can you share your repository section of pom / setting section. It seems some issue in it

Answer (score 0):

`net.sourceforge:kabeja:jar:0.4` lib is not present in maven central but at a different server (https://maven.openkm.com). See [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge/kabeja/0.4).

So you need to define another repository in your `pom.xml`.

```
<repository>
  <id>openkm</id>
  <url>https://maven.openkm.com/</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

I verified this jar is getting downloaded from above server only.

```
Downloading from openkm: https://maven.openkm.com/net/sourceforge/kabeja/0.4/kabeja-0.4.pom
Downloaded from openkm: https://maven.openkm.com/net/sourceforge/kabeja/0.4/kabeja-0.4.pom (392 B at 137 B/s)
Downloading from openkm: https://maven.openkm.com/net/sourceforge/kabeja/0.4/kabeja-0.4.jar
Downloaded from openkm: https://maven.openkm.com/net/sourceforge/kabeja/0.4/kabeja-0.4.jar (339 kB at 166 kB/s)
```

Comment: It is there in my POM file. But still seeing issue could not transfer artifact net.sourceforge:kabeja:pom:0.4 from/to snapshots

Comment: Does it work if you comment `http://snapshots` repository

Comment: No, commenting the snapshots. No help.

Comment: I am not sure then, something must be getting messed due to lots of proxy repositories you have configured. You can verify it by creating a new sample project and add the dependency and only required repository.

Comment: Error: https\://maven.openkm.com/.error=Could not transfer artifact net.sourceforge\:kabeja\:pom\:0.4 from/to openkm (https\://maven.openkm.com)\: Unexpected error\: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException\: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Comment: Can you create a sample project on GitHub so that I can replicate issue. It worked for me in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the TRUST STORE here resolved this issue.

**On Mac**

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxxxxxxx"
```

**On Windows**

Set Environment variable MAVEN_OPTS with the value `-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxxxxxxx`